# swift 3.0 how can i use Timer when in closure?

Tags: swift3, closures

```
detailRegisterVc.secondTime = {[weak self] time in
        self?.secondTime = time
        if time != 0 {
            self?.getIdentifierBtn.setTitle("\(time)s后获取验证码", for: UIControlState.normal)
            self?.countDownTimer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self?.timeFireMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            RunLoop.main.add((self?.countDownTimer!)!, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
        }
    }
```

Xcode throws an error:[_SwiftValue timeFireMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Are you using Xcode 8.0? Then, change `target: self` in the line `self?.countDownTimer = ...` to `target: self!`. (Forced unwrapping appended.) Swift 3.0.0 creates a mysterious instance of `_SwiftValue`, when Optional value passed to `Any`. Or else, update your Xcode to 8.1. Swift 3.0.1 automatically unwraps Optional when non-nil value is passed to `Any`.

Comment: i change self? to self! , but Xcode always throws the error.i think  the problem may happening on selector. in swift2 selector use String to find function,but in swift3.0 selector use function name to find function.but in closure i must use self?.timeFireMethod instead of  timeFireMethod

Comment: Do you really understand where to change? Not `self?` to `self!`, but `target: self` to `target: self!`. Selector notation is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved, just did not look carefully.

Comment: You are welcome, if my comment helped you solving the issue, it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run `Timer` from closure, but `Timer` didn't run on set `TimeInterval`. It looked like it was captured in closure. The thing that helped me was to run `Timer` on main thread.

```
@objc func updateDataModel() {
    ApiHelper().fetchCurrentlyPlayingInformation {  [weak self] (title, artwork, updateInSeconds) in

        self?.dataModel = DataModel(title: title, artwork: artwork, nextDataUpdateInSecs: updateInSeconds)
        self?.configureNowPlaying(with: self?.dataModel)
        self?.configureApiFetchTimer(with: updateInSeconds)
    }
}

func configureApiFetchTimer(with time: Int? = nil) {
    updateDataModelTimer?.invalidate()

    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let weakSelf = self else { return }

        let possibleDelay = 5.0
        let interval = TimeInterval(time ?? 30) + possibleDelay

        weakSelf.updateDataModelTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: weakSelf, selector: #selector(weakSelf.updateDataModel), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}
```